# AVAudioRecorder does not stay retained

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, release, dealloc, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder in my mac app. In my .m file I declare

```
@interface RecordViewController ()
{
    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
...
}
@end
```

further down I then alloc init the object like so:

```
audioRecorder = [[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recorderSettings error:&error] retain];
...
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
...
[audioRecorder record];
```

I can see that the file gets created, but it only has 4KB. I do not get an error but when I test if `[audioRecorder isRecording]` I can see that [audioRecorder is no longer recording. I am assuming that the object got released, even though I am not using ARC and the dealloc method was not called.

I had a similar problem with the AVAudioPlayer but the additional `retain]` appended to the alloc init solved that.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

I have even tried to do the following (all in the same method):

```
[audioRecorder record];
NSLog(@"recording is ... %d", [audioRecorder isRecording]);
```

and the result is 0.
???

Do I have to use `self` ? or lazily instantiate `audioRecorder`?

**UPDATE 2:**
I recreated the project - called it TEST and copied the source code from my old project. Now it works?!?! Go figure. The source codes are line for line the same. Is this a known problem with XCode?

Comment: Did you run zombies on the program to check the retain count? If `audioRecorder` was deallocated it seems like you would be getting a bad access error if you call `isRecording` on it.

Comment: If I run it in instruments no NSZombie gets created. I also don't get an error or bad access call when I call `isRecording`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, based on your comment, if you can still access the instance means that your object isn't dealloc.

AVAudioRecorder provide a delegate ([AVAudioRecorderDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorderDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioRecorderDelegate)) have you tried to use the delegate for log if the recording is successfully or you get some error?

Particularly the method  `audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:error:` should give you some error if occurred while recording.

BTW the additions `retain]` is not need because whit `alloc` `init` you've got the ownership of the object and you should release.

Comment: Had/have that delegate method implemented no error gets logged. I only added the retain because I noticed that a `AVAudioPlayer` object would not stay retained unless I did it. It would start playing for a split second and then cease. Once I added the `retain]` it played normally. I have even become paranoid and added the compiler flags `-fno-objc-arc` just to make sure that ARC really isn't active.

Comment: I also have `-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag` implemented and this never gets called.

Comment: And one more thing for clarification. When I call `[audioRecorder isRecording]` i.e. in an NSLog I get `0` as a result - but no error.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be released unless you release it, because you alloc and init and you don't release.( it's not autoreleased also.)

If ARC is enabled, it must be strong.

Please look at http://chinki-singh.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-record-audio-using.html

Comment: The only time I call `[audioRecorder release]` is in the `dealloc` method, which does not get called (I have a NSLog in the method to make sure). As mentioned I created a project without ARC being checked.

Comment: Ivars are `__strong` by default.